# Getting "unsupported_grant_type" error when getting bearer token from Reddit API in the GoLang

Tags: authentication, go, reddit

I am trying to get the bearer token from the Reddit API in the Golang with the code below. But I am getting `"error": "unsupported_grant_type"`. I tried the same configuration in the Postman and tried to run in python. Both of can get the token successfully. But in the GoLang it returns the error. I am new to GoLang. So please let me know if I am missing something.

```
func GetUserToken(username string, password string) string {
    type User struct {
        Username  string `json:"username"`
        Password  string `json:"password"`
        GrantType string `json:"grant_type"`
    }

    u := User{
        Username:  username,
        Password:  password,
        GrantType: "password",
    }

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := json.NewEncoder(&buf).Encode(u)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token", &buf)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    r.Header.Add("User-Agent", "my_unique_user_agent/0.0.1")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    app_id := "app.id"
    secret := "secret_string"
    // auth := app_id + ":" + secret
    // encodedAuth := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(auth))
    // r.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic "+encodedAuth)

    r.SetBasicAuth(app_id, secret)

    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    responseData, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Response Status:", res.Status)
    log.Println(string(responseData))

    return string(responseData)
}
}
```